# How to calculate the maximum spacing between Hemholtz coils

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I would like to design a long, uniform magnetic field using Hemholtz coils but am not sure how far I can separate them before the field lines diverge and become two loops that go around each coil rather than one which goes through both.

I have formulae for finding the magnetic flux at different points but I am not sure how to use them to determine this distance I am trying to calculate.

Does anyone have experience in this area who could offer some advice?

Comment: You can't separate Helmholtz coils at all. The homogeneity of the field depends explicitly on the precise placement of the coils at a distance equal to their radius. If you need a long uniform field you have to use a long solenoid. If you want to improve the homogeneity of the field at the end of the solenoid you can add additional turns on each end, but I don't know the ideal design parameters. The Helmholtz coil is designed to allow for a small field volume with max. homogeneity that is still easily accessible.

Comment: Ah that makes much more sense now. I need to put a ferrofluid mix between the coils to try and create a smooth flat surface in the viscous suspension after dropping objects into it. So it looks like I will need a radius half as long as my liquid container. Do you think that by having the bottom half of the coils one material (liquid), and the top half another (air), it will change the magnetic field at all?

Comment: Are you aware that air coils are not going to produce a strong field unless you have a fairly insane amount of power and water cooled coils? How much field are you trying to produce? Even with 1000A-turns you are only going to get into the 10mT range with 30cm Helmholtz coils, if my back of the envelope is correct... and 1000A-turns is probably already ambitious because of the heating. The strong magnetic effects that you are probably expecting from ferro-fluids are happening at 100 times stronger fields.

Comment: To round this up, this is what a strong experimental magnet to produce a homogeneous field volume looks like: http://www.magnetic-instrument.com/image/magnet-source/ms-1b.jpg. It's either one of these or a superconducting magnet, but that's a major investment (not that a large iron yoke magnet is cheap...).

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't aware that the field produced would be so weak. I was hoping to reproduce the effects that you see with neo magnets and ferrofluids, but without the spikes, so I could smooth the top of a viscous fluid without using some sort of wiper. I'm really lost for ideas now..

Comment: If you look at the Wikipedia page for Helmholtz coils, it gives you the formula. The performance "killer" is the permeability of free space, which is approx. 1.2e-6!  You have to make up for that with the number of turns multiplied with the current trough the coil i.e. $nI$. If you choose 1000 for $nI$, you are still at only around 1e-3T! The other factors for the size (1/R) and that you have two coils will boost it to about 1e-2T... so if you want to go much higher, you have to increase I to hundreds of Amperes and use water cooled coils, which is a major hassle. Magnets are hard!

Comment: To be honest, your best bet are permanent magnets. You can get 1-1.5T in fairly large volumes (2 inch diameter and 1 inch height, or so) for maybe a couple hundred $ worth of magnetic material... just be very carful with your fingers! These magnets are very strong and there is a lot of energy in that field. If you get caught up in two of these snapping together in an uncontrolled fashion, you will have pretty bad bruises, if not worse. You will have to manufacture some sort of magnetic yoke that can safely separate these magnets.